# File upload through MVC, jQuery, Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have created file uploader through MVC, jQuery, Ajax. But it is working 
fine for files of 1 to 3 kilobytes only, and is not working for files larger hajn that. How to upload lager-sized files?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" name="bfile"  size="50" id="bfile"/>
   <input type="butt
```

**AppAttachmentsController-controller code:**

```
 public string file_upload(string file_name, string file_binary)
        {

            byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(file_binary);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            string path=Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/upload/file"))+"\\"+file_name;
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                stream.CopyTo(fileStream);

            return "1";
        }
```

**jQuery, Ajax**:

```
function AttachemtPost() {
    var file_name = $("#bfile").val(); 
    var data = "file_name=" + file_name;
    var file = document.getElementById('bfile').files[0];
    var file_binary = file.getAsBinary();
    var file_size = file.fileSize;
    var file_text = file.getAsText("");
    alert('file :' + file_binary);
    alert('file size:' + file_size);
    data = "file_name=" + file_name + "&file_binary=" + file_binary;       
    ajaxlocalcall2(null, "POST", '@Url.Content("~/AppAttachments/file_upload")', data, "", "", "html", "oncontactinfosave");    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try increasing the maximum allowed request size in web.config which is 4MB by default:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="size in kbytes" />
```

Also if you host your application in IIS 7+ you should set the [request limit](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits):

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="size in bytes" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I tried this but more than 4kb file is not uploading .Please help

Comment: That's really strange. What numbers did you put in the `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength` attributes?